# creating an updating jqgrid from a websocket source

Tags: jquery, websocket, jqgrid

I am currently getting data from a websocket source as a json string and trying to populate a jqgrid. However only one row is displayed and that too with no data.
my websocket source is

```
  var json ;

    socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        if (! msg || ! msg.data) {
            return;
        }

       counter++;
       json = JSON.parse(msg.data);
         makeGrid(json);

}

$(document).ready(function() { 
    makeGrid(json);
}

function makeGrid(data){
    var json = [data]; // now this is local data
    console.log(json);
     $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            data: json, 
            datatype: "local", 
            colNames: [ "name", "value", "unit"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "name", width:30 ,height:"auto"},
                { name: "value", width: 15, align: "right",height:"auto" },
                { name: "unit", width: 10, align: "right" ,height:"auto"}
            ],
            pager: "#jqGridPager",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            rownumbers:true,
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "Messages.."
        }); 
 };
```

In my html file I have this..

```
`<table id="jqGrid"></table>` 
  <div id="jqGridPager"></div>
```

Please help..

Comment: You should create the grid (call `$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({...});`) **once**. At the next time you can reset new data using `$("#jqGrid").jqGrid("getGridPagam").data = newDataArray; $("#jqGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");` or to use `addRowData` to append row to the existing grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the grid (call `$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({...});`) **once**. At the next time you can reset new data using

```
var $grid = $("#jqGrid"), // the grid
    p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridPagam");

p.data = newDataArray;
$grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
```

or to use `addRowData` to append row to the existing grid.

Alternatively you can *recreate* the grid every time. To do this you can use `GridUnload` method *before* creating the grid. It will do nothing if the grid is still exist as initial `<table id="jqGrid"></table>`. During creating the grid `$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({...});` the initial table will be converted to relatively complex structure of divs and tables (see [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#the_first_grid) for example). On the other side reloading *the body* of the table is more effective as recreating the grid.

One more remark: the value `height:"auto"` in `colMode` is incorrect. It will be ignored and be used `150` instead.

Comment: I tried to add new row to existing table however I get an error on uidPref

Comment: function addRowToGrid(data){
  var json = [data];
  var rowId = $("#jqGrid").jgrid.uidPref + (++$("#jqGrid").jgrid.guid);
   $("#jqGrid").addRowData(rowId, json);
}  don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I realized my mistake . It had to be  var rowId = $("#jqGrid").uidPref + (++$("#jqGrid").guid); thank you

Comment: @user1351757: You can use `$("#jqGrid").addRowData(undefined, item);` to add the row of data.It will **generate** new unique rowid. On the other side it would be very good if every item of your data would contain the rowid as the part of data returned from the server. The error in your code exist becauce of the usage `$("#jqGrid").jgrid.uidPref` instead of `$.jgrid.uidPref`.

Comment: @user1351757: See [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.0/js/grid.base.js#L1531-L1535) and [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.0/js/grid.base.js#L6231-L6234)

Comment: I added a pager in my table to show 10 records at a time.. however after using the addrow functionality all data is shown directly via scrollbar rather than pagewise listing..

Comment: @user1351757: jqGrid have many methods and it supports many scenarios. `addRowData` ([addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) is *another* method for inline editing) is not good in case of large grid and paging of data. The best would be working with `data` parameter and reloading the grid, but providing unique id for every item of input data would be very important. It's not a problem in every real case.